# MVC 4 Html.BeginForm() doesn't upload multiple files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to upload two images from a form in MVC 4. I saw this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/), and it works fine the way Haaked did it, but when I tried to do the same by `@using(Html.BeginForm())` it doesn't work

I have the Action method from the controller that works for both scenarios:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Photo(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Photos/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Photo");
    }
```

The problem comes from the view. Here's the code from the Haaked website, for the view, that works:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />

    <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And here's my code that doens't.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />

    <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the **enctype** in the method overload of **Html.BeginForm** for file upload.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", FormMethod.Post,
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />

    <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />

    <input type="submit" />
}
```